# Appending to an Int to a collection of type [Int] gives 'not identical' error

Tags: ios, swift

Here's the code.

```
class Stack {
    var size: Int = 0
    var items: [Int] = []

    func push(element: Int) {
        items += element // Error - '[Int]' is not identical to 'UInt8'
    }
    func pop() -> Int {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
}
```

Everything is explicitly typed. How does the interpreter decide that my `element` is of `UInt8` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `+` has changed. You can use it only with two arrays. So you can say:

```
 items += [element]
```

However, I recommend using `append` instead.

Comment: Neat! I wonder why don't they update their online docs with all these changes? Where does one get to read about these obscure changes?

Comment: I quite enjoy reading them, if not for the sometimes outdated functionality :)

Comment: see: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW62